# ProcessStartInfo giving Error: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: vb.net, process

I want to run a command line which provision a computer but keep getting error The system cannot find the file specified. But when I run the code through cmd it works.

Below is the code

```
    Public Sub DjoinExe()
    Dim myProcessProperties As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim strArguments As New StringBuilder
    myProcessProperties.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\djoin.exe"
    If strArguments.Length <> 0 Then
        myProcessProperties.Arguments = " /provision /domain blablabla.com /machine machineName /reuse /savefile C:\Apps\offlinedomainjoin.txt "
    End If
    Dim myProcess As Process = Process.Start(myProcessProperties)

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the "file not found" error coming from your app or from the one you're running?  If it's the latter, setting the `WorkingDirectory` of the `ProcessStartInfo` to the path of the folder containing the EXE you're running may fix it.

Comment: It's coming from the one that I was running. I try         WorkingDirectory but still give me the same error message

Comment: Which line throws exception?

Comment: Are you compiling as x86, x64 or AnyCPU? And are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Windows?